# How and where to write if statement within PHP/MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

The following code works well when the correct URL is used like...
        http://example.com/user.php?id=joe

Where I need help is where do I add an if statement and how should it be written to provide either a default landing page or better, an input field so the visitor can retype the user name and submit it to have the correct page load.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', 'root', '');

// retrieve member's data
$ps = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ?");
    if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $ps->execute(array($_GET["id"]));
    }

$result = $ps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

extract($result);

echo $First_Name . ' - ' . $Email;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
  // YOUR PREVIOUS CODE HERE
} else {
  // REDIRECT CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: This is in the right direction and it answers the question that I asked. However, if the id is misspelled like using "joee" instead of "joe", I get "Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given". It even works if I remove the "id=".

Comment: Well you have to check if you have a valid result set after executing your query. I recommend opening another question for this if you cant figure it out on your own.

Comment: Thanks Merlin. I created another if statement for the $results array where the else provides a text input field to retype the id. The page does what I need it to do now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'd want to wrap all the code with the if statement so it doesn't run unless an id is present.

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) {
        //retrieve member data here and render normal page
    }
    else {
        //render landing page
    }
?>
```

It might be wise to put the code for rendering the two different pages into different functions to help with organization as well.

Comment: I was trying this originally, but it resulted in errors. The "!empty" was the ticket.